# Alternate apporach for using a flag in python

Tags: python

What is the best/alternate pythonic way for the code below,

```
 li=["Header",1,2,3,4,5]
 l=0
 for i in li:
    if l == 0:
       .....
       l += 1
    else:
       ....
```

Comment: It mostly depends on the code, hidden by `....`. Please, provide real usecase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can replace:

```
 l=0
 for i in li:
    if l ==0:
       frobnosticate(i)
       l+= 1
    else:
       twiddle(i)
```

With:

```
#do something with header outside the loop
frobnosticate(li[0])

#loop over everything but the first element
for i in li[1:]:
   twiddle(i)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
li=["Header",1,2,3,4,5]
do_stuff(li[0]) # first ....
for i in li[1:]:
    normal_stuff(i) # second ...
```

This will deal with header first and then iterate through rest of list.

Answer (score 0):

Accessing such pattern of elements using slicing is good enough. However, if data type in your list is not fixed/known, you may also use dictionary to redirect element to specified function:

```
def access_string_element(string):
    ....
def access_integer_element(integer):
    ....

access_table = dict()
access_table[str] = access_string_element
access_table[int] = access_integer_element
...
```

Then you could use the dict like this:

```
for element in li:
    access_table[type(element)](element)
```

This way benefits if you are going to handle list containing data with different data type. It would make your loop looks clearer, and easy to manage.

Have Fun ;)